# Visual Studio 2017: Text Template Custom Host: Exception in Code Analysis Metadata Reference

Tags: c#, code-generation, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to use this example from [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-text-template-host) on how to create a custom host for text template generation.

Every time I attempt to process a template using the host I get the following exception.  I've spent the last several hours attempting to find an answer from Google, but apparently my Google Fu just isn't working today.

```
An exception was thrown while trying to compile the transformation code. The following Exception was thrown:
System.ArgumentException: Empty path name is not legal.
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at Roslyn.Utilities.FileUtilities.OpenFileStream(String path)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(String path, MetadataReferenceProperties properties, DocumentationProvider documentation)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.CompilerBridge.<>c.<.ctor>b__15_0(String x)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<UnionIterator>d__66`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<UnionIterator>d__66`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray.CreateRange[T](IEnumerable`1 items)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ImmutableArrayExtensions.AsImmutableOrEmpty[T](IEnumerable`1 items)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Compilation.ValidateReferences[T](IEnumerable`1 references)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpCompilation.WithReferences(IEnumerable`1 references)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpCompilation.CommonWithReferences(IEnumerable`1 newReferences)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.CompilerBridge.PrepareNewCompilation()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.CompilerBridge.Compile()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.TransformationRunner.Compile(String source, String inputFile, IEnumerable`1 references, Boolean debug, SupportedLanguage language, String compilerOptions)
```